# Laravel ajax request to controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Hi I'm getting weird answer form my ajax request. This is my controller's method returning one of the id:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

//use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use App\Source;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response; //para user input post ajax


class RelationshipController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return "123";
    }
}
```

This is my route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::post('/requestId', 'RelationshipController@getUserId');

});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::resource('relationship', 'RelationshipController');
```

and this is my ajax request:

```
$("#consulta").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "requestId",
        type: 'post',
        data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, 'email': 'hihi'},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }, error: function () {
            alert("error!!!!");
        }
    });

});
```

I don't know why I'm getting this answer:

```
Object {message: ""}
message:""
__proto__:Object
```

What is wrong here? The route out of the route group doesn't work either. Im here btw:

```
Route::get('/createrelationship2/{og}/{dest}/{xchange}', 'RelationshipController@createrelationship2');
```

If I am on "/public/createrelationship" the ajax call works if I am on "/public/createrelationship2/10/5/1" the ajax call doesn't work. I don't understand..

Comment: Maybe try to return a valid JSON.

Comment: @jakubwrona what do u mean a valid json? doesn't work with a simple string? should work..

Comment: I guess your JS library is trying to build a json object from the json string returned from your controller, but your controller doesn't return json.

Comment: @jakubweona i write a json response and i get same answer

Comment: can you verify its reaching the controller, on your `getUserId()` method, insert a `dd('reached controller');`. On chrome, the developers tools search the network tabs and see if it spits out the `dd()`.

Comment: @Carlos I did it I still get the same answer, If i am on "/public/createrelationship" the ajax call works if i am on "/public/createrelationship2/10/5/1" the ajax call doesn't work. I dont understand..

Comment: is CSRF_TOKEN a js variable? or are you trying to call the laravel function `{{ csrf_token() }}"`

Answer (score 0):

What laravel version you are using? You can try replace **['middleware' => ['web']** to **['middleware' => ['api']**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api']], function () {

    Route::post('/requestId', 'RelationshipController@getUserId');

});
```

Comment: What laravel version? I created the same things in laravel 5.3.16 and all working correct. I've got 123 in browser console.

Comment: in version 5.3 but If I am on "/public/createrelationship" the ajax call works if I am on "/public/createrelationship2/10/5/1" the ajax call doesn't work. I don't understand it should I put another url?

Comment: How your route looks? For your second example your need route
`Route::post('/createrelationship2/{var1}/{var2}/{var3}', 'RelationshipController@getUserId');` 

in your routes/api.php file.

Comment: Wow that did all the work, I wrote the route like this:  Route::post('/createrelationship2/{og}/{dest}/{xchange}', 'RelationshipController@getUserId');